# Is it possible to attain 100% pass rate using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am Using Selneium Web driver + Java + firefox and i am going mad with the behaviour of selenium.

I have currently 300+ tests currently running in CI which takes nearly 5 hours for the test execution to complete.

My concern here is, every time i see the results of the tests there will be around 5-6 failures out of 300 tests which are not application failures.

And these 5-6 failures i see are not consistent, meaning, there are no definite set of 5 failures i observe every time.

In each run i see different set of failures.

And yes, 3 in 10 runs i see 100% pass rate.

The exceptions i come across are mainly StaleElementReference exception and NoSuchElement exception.

And yes, i handled AJAX calls and have necessary explicit waits and implicit waits.

Is this the way selenium behaves? can we not get 100% pass rate consistently?

I know this question is way too generic. But i am really frustrated and would like to know am i the only one facing this issue or there are other folks as well.

Comment: Same issues here. Using Selenium with HtmlUnit. It is slow, and it is not passing 100% neither.

Comment: We are using `FluentWait` for every Selenium interaction, which fixed all StaleElementReferences and NoSuchElements for us.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have 100% pass rate on Selenium tests, if your tests are well-written.

What you have are flaky tests. See http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html

Comment: Thanks for the sharing a great article!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have 100% pass rate but it really depends on your test environment setup. You have to have all elements synchronized via waiting etc. but in some cases communication between webdriver and web browser fails anyway (but there are improvements in new versions). So basically with webdriver intermittent tests are more common. Because you didn't write more details there are generic options:

- restart web browser after few tests (e.g. after each test class)
- remember failed tests and use some re-run mechanism in your test environment
- use screenshots to map test/browser state and if something fails you will see it and you can investigate possible (sync) problems

These options are more like workarounds than properly solution. For webdriver it's important to synchronize test state and web browser state.

Comment: I actually open a new browser instance for each test. I can not actually re-run the failed tests because of the data restrictions in my test cases. I am running the tests in CI with the same build and same database everyday. So if the build and database are same, then ideally the behaviour of the tests should also be same

Comment: Yes, ideally it should be, but ... If you restart browser after each test it looks there are problems with sync between browser and tests. This is typical behavior for webdriver you can use screenshots or record video from web browser to see what happens and then just search problem. Also you can split problematic tests to smaller peaces if it's possible.